# Forcefully Preventing EF from Inserting an Already Existing Object

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

We have `Users`, and `Roles` with a Many-to-Many relationship defined.

The Fluent API that defines Role:

```
public RoleMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.RoleString);

    // Properties
    this.Property(t => t.RoleString)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("Roles");
    this.Property(t => t.RoleString).HasColumnName("Role");

    // Relationships
    this.HasMany(t => t.Users)
        .WithMany(t => t.Roles)
        .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("UserRoles");
                m.MapLeftKey("Role");
                m.MapRightKey("UserName");
            });
}
```

the following code *(as expected)* wants to insert a new Role in Roles, then a matching record in UserRoles for the user "MrAdmin".

```
var user = db.Users.Find("MrAdmin");
user.Roles.Add(new Role("Administrator"));
db.SaveChanges();
```

I very specifically DO NOT want to lookup the already existing "Administrator" role from the Roles table. The actual application has an enum of Roles that get passed in, so the user does not need to be aware of the Roles table or any of its content at all.

In other words, **I know the following code works**, but I am looking to manipulate EF at a lower level:

```
var adminRole = db.Roles.Find("Administrator");
var user = db.Users.Find("MrAdmin");
user.Roles.Add(adminRole);
db.SaveChanges();
```

**What I'm trying to do is force EF to avoid adding any -- or already existing -- records to the Roles table.**

I have attempted two approaches:

**1)** Create an INSTEAD OF INSERT TRIGGER on the DB side, to simply accept the insert request and not let EF worry about it. But EF still knew something was fishy and threw an exception.
Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_DontThrowOnInsert] ON [dbo].[Roles]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @ROLE as varchar(50)
    SELECT @ROLE = [Role] from inserted

    IF EXISTS(SELECT [Role] FROM dbo.Roles WHERE [Role] = @ROLE) 
        UPDATE dbo.Roles 
        SET [Updated] = GetUtCDate() 
        output inserted.[Role]
        WHERE [Role] = @Role
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO dbo.Roles
        output inserted.[Role]
        SELECT * FROM inserted
        WHERE [Role] not in (SELECT [Role] FROM dbo.Roles)
END
```

**2)** override the SaveChanges() in DBContext, and mark the suspect entries as Unchanged:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    this.ChangeTracker.Entries<Role>().ForEach(r => r.State = EntityState.Unchanged);
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Exception:

> Result Message:   System.InvalidOperationException : Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type
>   'Manufacturing.Domain.LookupRole' have the same primary key value.
>   Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that
>   database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the
>   database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer
>   for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the
>   'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or
>   'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use EF 6 Interceptors. IDbCommandTreeInterceptor and IDbCommandInterceptor
...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx#BuildingBlocks/